# how to get the actual value from division of two double variables

Tags: c#, variables, double

I have the next code as clear in the following image:
[image]

let's say I have the following values in the variables:

```
xRegs.HeaderRatePrice = 0.035
xRegs.AccCurrPrice = 1435
```

the result that I got in "xRegs.AccRatePrice" is : 2.439024390243902e-5

but as I know the value must be : 0.000024

I tried to convert the result by converting it tostring("E2") but I didn't got the correct result.

how can I get it?

Comment: It seems to me like you probably want to use `decimal` instead of `double` here, if you expect values to be *exactly* as you specified them in decimal.

Comment: here I don't expect the decimals values

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Even the Windows Calculator gives the same answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOJts.png

Comment: @gunr2171 that's what I mean, I need to convert that value to the actual value 0.000024

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual value 0.000024"? That *isn't* the exact result of 0.035/1435. If you multiple 0.000024 by 1435, you get 0.03444.

Answer (score 2):

`2.439024390243902e-5` is the true result of 0.035 divided by 1435.
`0.000024` would be that number rounded to six decimal digits.
So just set your format string accordingly.

```
xRegs.HeaderRatePrice = 0.035;
xRegs.AccCurrPrice = 1435;
xRegs.AccRatePrice = string.Format("{0:F6}", xRegs.HeaderRatePrice / xRegs.AccCurrPrice);
// or xRegs.AccRatePrice = $"{(xRegs.HeaderRatePrice / xRegs.AccCurrPrice):F6}";
```